# Cocoa-Touch internals: How does the view know its controller?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios

If you add a subview to a view or add a view to a window, how does iOS know which controller this view belongs too?

*Easy example:*
Have a UIView without `UIViewController` and add it to the window `[window addSubView:myView]` --> it will not rotate.
Now use a `UIViewController`, have it implement `shouldAutoRotateToInterfaceOrientation:` and add the controller's view to the window: `[window addSubView:myController.view]` --> **magically**, the view will adjust to interface orientation.

But look at the code: in both cases a `UIView` was added. How can iOS possibly be aware that in the second case a `UIViewController` was involved?

I'm interested in how this is done internally. My best guess is that `UIViewController.view` is a setter which adds the controller to an internal array of controllers or assigns itself to some internal variable which holds the currently active controller.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple.  Look in `UIView.h`.  It's right there.  Each `UIView` has a pointer back to a `UIViewController` (which is apparently referred to as the "viewDelegate").

Comment: 1. I don't understand why this "_viewDelegate" is such a hidden thing then. Most of the implementations I have seen pass "self" (being the UIViewController) to the view, so the view (e.g. a UITableView) can grab data from its controller. Why not directly allow access to "_viewDelegate"? 
2. And how does this "_viewDelegate" property get populated? What is setting it? If in the controller I have the line "self.view = [[UIView alloc] init]", how can the view know about the UIViewController?

Comment: @Krumelur my guess: there's not a 1-to-1 mapping between view controllers and views (ie, every view does not have a unique view controller), and the value of this ivar can (likely) change at unexpected time as the window view hierarchy changes.

Answer (score 1):

[Dave DeLong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5640081/cocoa-touch-internals-how-does-the-view-know-its-controller/5640193#5640193) is correct (and gets +1) as it is clearly defined UIView.h as @package so anything in UIKit can access it.

Here is an example of accessing that variable for educational purposes only (obviously you will not do this in a real application).

**SomeAppDelegate.m**

```
@synthesize navigationController=_navigationController;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    // Add the navigation controller's view to the window and display.
    self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    //DO NOT TRY THIS AT HOME
    UIView *mynavview = self.navigationController.view;
    //Guaranteed _viewDelegate atleast in iOS 4.3
    Ivar ivar = class_getInstanceVariable([UIView class], "_viewDelegate");
    UIViewController *controller = object_getIvar(mynavview, ivar);
    NSLog(@"controller = self.navigationController? %@", controller == self.navigationController ? @"Yes" : @"No");

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code example. A question about "self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;": is this the same as if adding the view as subview to the window?

Comment: Yes its the new cool way so people dont complain about the magic of just adding the view :). Adding the view to UIWindow still works fine. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWindow_Class/UIWindowClassReference/UIWindowClassReference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006817-CH3-SW33

Comment: Okay, see my comment above to Dave DeLong's answer: If I use the standard non-cool way, how can the view know about the controller it belongs to? And your answer leads yet to another question: if I add one view of a controller to the window as subview and then another (also controller+view combo), shouldn't my first view get removed (according to the link in your comment)?

Comment: It is the same way, I just used a default example. Comment that line out and put `[self.window addSubview:self.navigationController.view];` and you will still get the same result.

Comment: Joe, I know that. I just don't know how the view will know about its controller. When/where is the hidden "_viewDelegate" set? If inside the UIViewController the view is created and assigned to self.view, how can the view know which controller it belongs to? Does "self.view" set the property (must!)?

Comment: I dont know the internal details but think about it. The `UIViewController` knows when a view is added or removed because outside of UIKit we are limited to using the view property. So when a view is set the controller can say `oldView->_viewDelegate = nil; newView->_viewDelegate = self` or call a private UIKit method if one exists to set it.

Comment: Yeah, that would also be my guess. Thanks.

Comment: No problem I completely understand your curiosity. WHY would they do that then hide it from us! My guess it is to help enforce the whole MVC pattern.

Comment: Ah missed that. No from my experience it stacks them but only the subview at index 0 seems to get rotation notifications. All other views on top do not. I had to create an overlay for an entire application that rotates properly and ended up having to use two UIWindows in my application.

Answer (score 0):

UIViewController has a private class method (called `controllerForView:`, I believe) which is used to find the view's controller. Internally, there is probably a table used to connect the two together, and this method simply finds the proper location in that table and returns its value. When the result is nil, the default implementation will be used (don't rotate).

If you want to be sure about the name of the method, set a breakpoint in `-[UIView becomeFirstResponder]`, tap on a text field, and step through the code until it shows up in the call stack. I suggest using `becomeFirstResponder` because it is easier to control than most things which get the view controller.